# Angularjs: $scope vs scope

Tags: angularjs

In Angularjs, is there a specific reason to use `$scope` in controllers and `scope` (without `"$"`) in directives link function?  Is it just a convention or anything else?

Comment: It's just a variable name, so not really.

Comment: similar question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18719140/angular-link-function-scope-vs-scope/18719347#comment27583647_18719347)

Comment: You can find also a very good video answer to this question by John Lindquist here:
[http://egghead.io/lessons/angularjs-scope-vs-scope](http://egghead.io/lessons/angularjs-scope-vs-scope).

Answer (score 29, accepted):

The case when you do `$scope` in controller the Dependency Injection injects scope based on matching the variable name `$scope`, in this case using `scope` as name would not work.

For case of directive the injection is position based so you can name your variable `a` or `b` or any thing. The directive order for link function is

`(scope, iElement, iAttrs, controller)`

so first element is always scope object.

Comment: I would clarify the latter part as "For case of the directive link function, the injection is position based, so using `scope` is really just convention."  (I can't find any good explanation why `$scope` isn't used here, as well, if only for consistency)

Answer (score 2):

The module factory methods like *controller, directive, factory, filter, service, animation, config and run* receive arguments through dependency injection (DI). In case of DI, you inject the **scope object** with the dollar prefix i.e. **$scope**. The reason is the **injected arguments** must match to the names of **inject-able objects** followed by dollar ($) prefix.

**For example**, you can inject the scope and element objects into a controller as given below:

```
module.controller('MyController', function ($scope, $element) { // injected arguments });
```

When the methods like directive linker function don’t receive arguments through dependency injection, you just pass the **scope object** without using dollar prefix i.e. **scope**. The reason is the passing arguments are received by its caller.

```
module.directive('myDirective', function () // injected arguments here 
{ 
    return { 
         // linker function does not use dependency injection 
         link: function (scope, el, attrs) { 
            // the calling function will passes the three arguments to the linker: scope, element and attributes, in the same order 
         } 
    }; 
});
```

In short, in case of dependency injection the **scope object** is received as **$scope** while in case of non-dependency injection **scope object** is received as **scope** or with any name.

Answer (score 1):

The reason of this behavior is that, Unlike controllers, directives don't use dependency injection, instead they are passed the scope created by the controller that is placed behind the view. 
this is very tricky, So you can reuse your directive on different scopes.

Answer (score 1):

The `$` in `"$scope"` indicates that the scope value is being injected into the current context.

`$scope` is a service provided by `$scopeProvider`. You can inject it into controllers, directives or other services using Angular's built-in dependency injector:

```
module.controller(function($scope) {...})
```

which is shorthand for

```
module.controller(['$scope', function($scope) {...}])
```

However, `scope` could be anything, it's a function parameter name, could be `foo` or `a12342saa`.

```
function link( scope, element, attributes ) {
    //  Only scope 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The "$" in "$scope" indicates that the scope value is being injected into the current context. But, not all references to scope are based on dependency injection.