# How do I create a directive controller?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

My problem is, I cannot find any official documentation about this.

https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive uncommentedly suggests

`controller: ['$scope', function($scope) {`

Why can't I omit the `$`s here, as in the `link function(scope, elem, attrs) {`? `controller: ['scope', function(scope) {` will result in the error `"Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: scopeProvider <- scope`

What's the syntax here?

Comment: The `$scope` in `function($scope)` is an alias. You can rename it to `function(scope)`.

Comment: no I cannot. see updated answer

Comment: Not sure if you renamed `$scope` to `scope` in the code block. Please check my answer with working code below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A directive's **link** function is just a normal JavaScript function that has a type signature of **scope**, **element**, **attributes** object in that order. If were to flip around the arguments and declare our link function like:

```
link: function(attr, elem, scope) {
      console.log(scope)
    }
```

The first parameter (now called attr) would STILL be the scope object.

Unlike link functions, controller functions are called by Angular's injection system.

`"$"` in `"$scope"` indicates that the scope value is being injected into the current context. But, not all references to scope are based on dependency injection. For example, in `$watch, link, and cloning` functions (not an exhaustive list), scope is always passed as a positional argument, regardless of its name.

You can refer these articles:
**[$scope vs scope](https://egghead.io/lessons/angularjs-scope-vs-scope)**

[angular - $scope vs scope](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19288586/angularjs-scope-vs-scope)

Answer (score 0):

The `$scope` in `function($scope)` is an alias of the dependency `'$scope'`. You can rename it there.

[Edited Plunkr from the documentation](http://plnkr.co/edit/MkCB8CYfywvmzy5fRZ0F?p=preview)

Relevant part of the JS code:

```
      controller: ['$scope', function(scope) { // "scope" as an alias
        var panes = scope.panes = [];

        scope.select = function(pane) { // $scope renamed
          angular.forEach(panes, function(pane) {
            pane.selected = false;
          });
          pane.selected = true;
        };

        this.addPane = function(pane) {
          if (panes.length === 0) {
            scope.select(pane); // $scope renamed
          }
          panes.push(pane);
        };
      }],
```

Answer (score 0):

- The official documentation about the so-called `directive definition object` can be found in the [API Reference for $compile](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile).
- The `directive controller constructor function` is injectable with the locals `$scope`, `$element`, `$attrs` and `$transclude`. These are injected. Thus, their exact spelling **matters**.
- Creating a `directive controller` via `controller:function($scope) {}` is the same as creating it like `controller:['$scope', function(scope) {}]`.